# How to split a read Text File into "\n"s?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, file, ifstream

I need to split a text file into sentences, which are separated by moving to the next line.

Imagine this text:

```
Hey what's up
How are you doing?
Enjoy your coding!
```

This is the way I figured out to get the text from the file and save it:

```
ifstream file;
string text, finaltext;
file.open("input.txt", ios::in);

    while(getline(file, text)){
    finaltext += text;
}

cout<<finaltext;
```

So this actually **does the job**, but for a weird reason it Skips the "\n", and the result I get is this:

```
Hey what's upHow are you doing?Enjoy your coding!
```

So i need to find a new way to do this, making sure that *finaltext* gets the text separated by "\n"s. Can someone please help me? I'd be forever grateful. Thank you guys.

Comment: All you have to do is add the line `finaltext += '\n';` at the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: `"but for a weird reason it skips the "\n" "` -- The reason is not weird. The documentation for [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) clearly states that it discards the newline character. So, if you want it back, you must add it manually.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting each line seperately, you can try something like this:

```
file.open("input.txt", ios::in);

while (getline(file, text)) {
    finaltext += text;
    finaltext += "\n";
}
```

This way, you're adding the newline character yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the functions `ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, FILE *restrict stream)` (which you get when you run `man getline`) and `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str)` which you are using. From the manpage of the first one:

> getline() reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of the buffer containing the text into *lineptr.  The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.

From the manpage of the second one:

> If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded (i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it).

This might explain your confusion. So, as others have said, you'll just have to add it yourself.

Comment: Note that the first function you are talking about is not part of ISO C++, but is specific to POSIX platforms. However, you may still be correct that this is the reason for OP's confusion. Another possible source of confusion would be the function [`std::fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets), which is part of ISO C++ and also does not discard the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you just needed to concatenate '\n'

```
while (getline(file, text))
    {
        finaltext =finaltext + "\n" + text;
    }

    cout << finaltext;
```

As mentioned by Sandburg, `+` operator was almost deprecated with C++17 so you can use `append()` or `insert()` here.

Comment: I am maybe not up to date, but `string operator+` was almost deprecated:
 *operator+ should be used with great caution when stateful allocators are involved (such as when std::pmr::string is used) (since C++17). Prior to P1165R1, the allocator used for the result was determined by historical accident and can vary from overload to overload for no apparent reason.*

Comment: @Sandburg You are right it is indeed deprecated, I didn't knew about that. Thanx